# How to open an iFrame on a select date

Tags: javascript, iframe

We currently have an iframe to show a form widget from a booking engine (www.rezdy.com)
The iframe reads:

```
            <iframe seamless="" width="300px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" class="rezdy" src="https://tktsmallorca.rezdy.com/calendarWidget/271820?iframe=true&targetFrame=_new_modal"></iframe>
```

The form has a date select calendar. Is there a way we can add to this code so that when the page opens a preselect date is already highlighted? For example 13th November?

Thank you

Comment: If you are not able to select the date via the src URL then you can not do it. Maybe it is possible with the URL but this depends on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access content in an `iframe`, when the `src` is on a different domain. So it is not possible to preselect the date.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help